# Moving domains not supported?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, active-directory

I have a SharePoint 2013 farm (multiple servers that connects to a sql cluster). The entire farm needs to move to a different AD domain. The SharePoint servers, the SQL cluster, the service accounts, and the users accounts. The old domain is being shut off, so everything needs to move. There is an [article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/269196) on support.microsoft.com that shows that moving the sql cluster is not supported.

I see forum posts saying that moving SP is not supported either, but can't find mention of this from official sources. I'm assuming I need to treat this like a migration and backup the content and service databases and restore them to a new farm that's been created in the new domain, but does anyone know of an official source of this info?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cant move SharePoint farm to new domain, Reason, their are hard-coded references in the config DB related to services, web application, servers etc. For single server it is ok but for multiple server farm, Big no. You have to create a new config db using the new domain servers.

So best way is(which you already mentioned) migrate.

- build a new farm with new SQL cluster, new service accounts
- create new service Applications( some you can use exisitng DBs)
- create new web applications
- deploy all the custom solutions and custom configuration(if any)
- now mount the database to respected web application.
- migrate the user from old domain to new doamin.

also check [this](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/c91a915e-1b5e-4d93-ad44-a4add90ba4b6/move-sharepoint-2013-farm-servers-to-another-ad-forest?forum=sharepointgeneral) and [this one, reply from MSFT](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/20ab9c73-ab38-47d0-a791-8f9004fbe1a4/move-sharepoint-farm-servers-to-another-ad-domain?forum=sharepointadminlegacy)

Answer (score 1):

Don't migrate Sharepoint to another domain, I don't think it is not supported 
It is simply painful. Cleaner way is to rebuild the farm in new domain and do SP content database detach\attach procedure (as in DR or Upgrade scenario). In the past for domain move I was trying to use this blog: http://aurramu.blogspot.com.es/2011/06/move-sharepoint-from-domain-to-another.html but with mixed results - if you farm is simple (no enterprise services) then you will be fine, but the more complex set up (Excel, PowerPivots etc) you will most probably end up rebuilding those services anyway, so I prefer a clean build and then move content.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was thinking as well. I was hoping to find some official guidance from MS, as I'm anticipating the looks from IT who were planning on changing the domain and rebooting.